# Macbook Pro going into sleep at 132.8F (56C)?

Tags: macbook-pro

When looking into behavior for overheating I am seeing other posts that say anything up to *at least* 158F (70C) should be just fine.  Why might I see this behavior?

Note that I did clean out with compressed air six months ago: before that time the laptop had been getting into the mid sixties. But 56C ??

I am using smc Fan Control to a ) keep the CPU cooled and b ) monitor the temperature.

Comment: Which temperature sensor is 56ºC? Some may be much higher than that. [Also, please check for the shutdown cause and compare it to this list](https://georgegarside.com/blog/osx/shutdown-causes/) so we know exactly what's overheating.

Comment: @JMY1000  smcFanControl for the sensor.  How to check for the cause? I saw this in System log  "6/7/16 9:19:38.484 PM CommCenter[600]: Telling CSI to go low power."

Comment: Ah, I thought it shut down. Use something like [iStat Pro](http://forums.macrumors.com/attachments/istat-pro-wdgt-zip.422723/) or [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/) to monitor the temperatures of all your sensors.